# Что делает данная строка?

Tags: python

Что делает данная строка?

```
R=[0]+Log[:]+[L]
```

Comment: Складывает три списка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся информация есть в официальной документации: [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

`[0]` — список с единственным элементом.

`Log[:]` — слайс списка. Если не указаны начало и конец, делается поверхностная копия списка. Более читаемая версия: `Log.copy()`.

`[L]` — список с единственным элементом.

Операция сложения для списков создаёт новый список — результат их конкатенации.

`R = [0, Log[0], Log[1], ..., Log[n], L]`